# liquibase rollback always rollsback to a clean empty database

Tags: mysql, version, liquibase, rollback

I've been trying to learn Liquibase and now and trying to perform a simple roll back.  But when it executes it always rolls back to a fresh database even though I'm only trying to rollback to a specific tag.  My command line is below...

java -jar liquibase.jar --changeLogFile=/media/GALACTUS/Documents/CHANGELOGS/CH_Q_10.xml rollback "1.0.0-RELEASE"

The change log I'm using is pasted below as well.  I would expect this to end up going to the version 1.0.0 database but it just completely rolls the entire thing back.  I've confirmed the version tag is in the changelog so I"m not sure what I'm missing.

```
<databaseChangeLog

        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">


    <changeSet id="1" author="root">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <tableExists tableName="student" schemaName="public"/>
        </preConditions>
        <createTable tableName="student">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="enrolled" type="boolean" defaultValueBoolean="false"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="2" author="root">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <columnExists tableName="student" columnName="grade" schemaName="public"/>
        </preConditions>
        <addColumn tableName="student">
            <column name="grade" type="DECIMAL(4,2)" />
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="3" author="root">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <columnExists tableName="student" columnName="enrolled" schemaName="public"/>
        </preConditions>
        <dropColumn 
            columnName="enrolled"
            tableName="student"/>
            <rollback>ALTER TABLE student ADD COLUMN enrolled boolean;</rollback>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="4" author="root" >
        <tagDatabase tag="1.0.0-RELEASE"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="5" author="root">
        <createTable tableName="instructor">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="start_date" type="varchar(50)" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="6" author="root" >
        <tagDatabase tag="1.1.0-RELEASE"/>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Below is a shot of my change log showing the version tag, but it never rollsback to that tag, it just continues to rollback everything.

[Version tags in Changelog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSWzw.png)

Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated, from everything I've read it seems like this should be rather straight forward and I'm a bit baffled.

Comment: Have you tried to specify tag without quotes: java -jar liquibase.jar --changeLogFile=/media/GALACTUS/Documents/CHANGELOGS/CH_Q_10.xml rollback 1.0.0-RELEASE  ?

Comment: Yes, I had tried that first, both ways end up with the same issue rolling back the DB all the way.  But the job succeeds using quotes and without.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Liquibase starts rolling back and continues until it finds the specified label. So, I would check whether there is a reason that it doesn't see a matching label, like a typing error in the label. I noticed that in the command there is a space between "1.0.0-" and "RELEASE" and that space is not in the label in the changelog.

Comment: Admittedly I forgot to update this but I believe you are correct and the issue was just a syntax problem with the space.  I'll take my lashings accordingly for not updating in a timely manner.